# Is AWS CloudWatch supported on Alpine Docker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, alpine-linux

Has anyone ever installed the AWS CloudWatch in the Alpine docker?   Seems to me it is not supporting for all the installation packages AWS provided.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/download-cloudwatch-agent-commandline.html

We can install in this way:

RUN apk update && apk add ca-certificates curl rpm
RUN wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazoncloudwatch-agent/amazon_linux/amd64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.rpm
RUN rpm -ihv --nodeps ./amazon-cloudwatch-agent.rpm

But it is not functioning correctly.   If I want to check its status

~/test # /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -m ec2 -a status

I get the error.

/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl: line 469: systemctl: not found

For me, I don't think it is not compatible in Alpine (I am using alpine:3.14).   Anyone has some idea on this?

Thanks,

````
#To install aws-cloudwatch-agent

RUN apk update && apk add ca-certificates curl rpm
RUN wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazoncloudwatch-agent/amazon_linux/amd64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.rpm
RUN rpm -ihv --nodeps ./amazon-cloudwatch-agent.rpm 

#To setup repo for k6 and install k6
ENV RUN_IN_CONTAINER="True"
RUN wget https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/cloudposse-dev/packages/alpine/any-version/main/x86_64/k6-0.34.1-r0.apk
RUN apk add --allow-untrusted k6-0.34.1-r0.apk ```

Thanks in advance!

RD
````

Answer (score 0):

Seems just need to use the docker multiple stages to build what you want:

If we want to do the integration of K6 and AWS CloudWatch (to make them in one docker files with Alpine.

1. Checkout git@github.com:grafana/k6.git
2. Update the docker files to

```
FROM golang:1.17-alpine as builder_k6
WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/go.k6.io/k6
ADD . .
RUN apk --no-cache add git
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go install -a -trimpath -ldflags "-s -w -X go.k6.io/k6/lib/consts.VersionDetails=$(date -u +"%FT%T%z")/$(git describe --always --long --dirty)"

FROM debian:latest as builder_cw

RUN apt-get update &&  \
    apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN curl -O https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazoncloudwatch-agent/debian/amd64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.deb && \
    dpkg -i -E amazon-cloudwatch-agent.deb && \
    rm -rf /tmp/* && \
    rm -rf /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-config-wizard && \
    rm -rf /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl && \
    rm -rf /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config-downloader

FROM alpine:latest

COPY --from=builder_cw /tmp /tmp
COPY --from=builder_cw /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
COPY --from=builder_cw /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent
COPY --from=builder_k6 /go/bin/k6 /usr/bin/k6

ADD statsd.json /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/default_linux_config.json
ADD statsd.json /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/statsd.json
ADD credentials /root/.aws/credentials
ADD config /root/.aws/config

#startup the agent
ENV RUN_IN_CONTAINER="True"
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/start-amazon-cloudwatch-agent"]
```